# Javascript - JSON Stringify raw string (no additional escapes)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a xml file whose content I need to read and convert into a json file. The content of the xml file should be copied as is and put into the json file. 
This works mostly without any issues, if the xml file however contains strings such as `<data key="foo">foo\nbar</data>` the generated json file will contain `foo\\nbar` because the backslash is escaped.

I could iterate over the input string and replace all two char occurrences of `\` and `n` with a single `\n` but then I have to do the same thing for `\t`, `\b`, `\f` and so on.
Is there a way to prevent this and just stringifying the "raw" content?

---

My code to read and convert the xml file basically looks like this

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const xml2js = require("xml2js");

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

async function main() {
    const fileContent = await readFile("data/test.xml");
    const dataFields = (await xml2js.parseStringPromise(fileContent))["root"]["data"];
    const result = dataFields.reduce((previous, current) => {
        const key = current["$"].key;
        const value = current["_"];
        previous[key] = value;
        return previous;
    }, {});

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}

main();
```

Example xml file:

```xml
<root>
<data key="foo">foo\nbar</data>
<data key="qux">qux\\nquux</data>
</root>
```

The actual output

```
{
  "foo": "foo\\nbar",
  "qux": "qux\\\\nquux"
}
```

although I want the desired output of

```
{
  "foo": "foo\nbar",
  "qux": "qux\\nquux"
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, what environment are you running it on?

Comment: @AndreasPizsa Windows 10, Node v12.13.0

Comment: When you redirect the output to a file, what does the file contain?

Comment: When you run your code and it prints on the screen are the quotation marks escaped as well? Is the output more like `"{\"foo\":\"foo\\nbar\",\"qux\":\"qux\\\\nquux\"}"`?

Comment: The content is the same if redirected to a file or printed to stdout. 
The quotation marks are not escaped since there are none in the xml file, they are escaped if they are present in the xml file, e.g. `<data key="foo">"foo\nbar"</data>`

Comment: Then the escaping seems to be happening in xml2js, as it’s not in JSON.stringify. Doing `console.log(JSON.stringify({foo: 'foo\nbar'}, null, 2))` outputs results correctly as expected. What happens if you do `console.log(result)`?

Comment: `console.log(result);` prints
`{ foo: 'foo\\nbar', qux: 'qux\\\\nquux' }` 

---------
`console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));` prints
`{ foo: 'foo\\nbar', qux: 'qux\\\\nquux' }`

---------
**But** `console.log(result.foo);` prints `foo\nbar`

Comment: I think this is either related to the object creation or to the `toJson` function because the value returned by xml2js is what I would expect and prints fine on its own.

Comment: `console.log(dataFields)` is already messed up, so it’s coming from xml2js. `[
  { _: 'foo\\nbar', '$': { key: 'foo' } },
  { _: 'qux\\\\nquux', '$': { key: 'qux' } }
]`

Comment: why does `console.log(result.foo);` work though?  Printing `console.log(dataFields[0]["_"]);` is also fine, inspecting the object itself e.g. via VS Codes Debug Console is fine as well `Object {_: "foo\nbar", $: Object}`

Comment: Even `result` seems to be fine (according to the debugger): `Object {foo: "foo\nbar", qux: "qux\\nquux"}`.

Comment: Additionally I don't think we should take `console.log(JSON.stringify({foo: 'foo\nbar'}, null, 2))` into consideration, because `\n` in this case is a single character and not two.

Comment: Looking at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andrew8088/6f53af9579266d5c62c8#file-stringify-js-L14) and given it yields the same results as `JSON.stringify` the escaping seems to happen in the implementation, e.g. `return '"' + val.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"') + '"';` As I don't see any customiazation points I guess the fastest way would be to implement my own `stringify`.

Comment: It’s easy to get confused between a string value enclosed by "" and that value being printed on screen :) It only appears right because "\\n" prints on the console as \n.

Comment: Oh. We have it all wrong, and it’s all good. No extra escaping here :) The correct string representation of the characters in the XML actually is 'foo\\nbar'. You need to actually replace that with the control character :)

Comment: Aside from the solution below, the `null` argument in `stringify` is a replacer function which you can use to custzomize the output, so you don’t need to write a full `JSON.stringify` implementation. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters.

That’s just FYI though. The correct implementation is in the solution I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point here is that everything is working as expected. The correct escaped string representation of text `foo\nbar` actually is `"foo\\nbar"`.

When you do `console.log("foo\\nbar")` you get `foo\nbar` printed to the console.

Now, what you actually want though is for the input text to be *unescaped* a linefeed.

So that this text:

`foo\nbar`

should become this text:

`foo
bar`

The escaped string representation of the latter being `"foo\nbar"`

There’s a package for that, and I’m applying it in the `reduce` function.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const xml2js = require('xml2js')
const unescape = require('unescape-js')

async function main() {
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('test.xml', 'utf-8')
  const xml = await xml2js.parseStringPromise(fileContent)
  const result = xml.root.data
    .reduce((result, {_, $}) => ({
      ...result,
      [$.key]: unescape(_)
    }), {})

  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
}

main()
```